# Возможна ли передача файла через websocket?

Tags: php, websocket, ratchet

Использую Ratchet php, я пытался считать файл по байтам и отправить их, но что-то не очень это ворк, есть ли другие способы ?

Comment: Ну так-то вы правильно делали.. Можно делить файл на байты и поочередно отправлять по Х байтов, при этом надо учитывать что если соединение разорвалось - продолжать надо с последнего переданного байта... Но какой смысл так извращаться если есть xhr - непонятно...

Comment: А какое максимальное кол-во символов, что бы все это дело не улетало